# StringCchVPrintf vs sprintf_s

Tags: c++, winapi

Which function should I prefer for new projects? 
StringCchVPrintf from strsafe.h or sprintf_s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) if you code in C (because `snprintf` is in the C99 standard).

If you code in C++, consider using [std::ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/), which is in C++ standard library.

Both `snprintf` and `ostringstream` should be available on many systems, including non Windows ones.

I generally suggest coding for standards when possible. It will ease the port of your software to other systems. Try to avoid (or at least be careful when) using functions only available in WinApi (AFAIK, there is no standard specification defining it; it is simply a proprietary implementation, and most other systems don't have it).

If your application has a graphical interface, you could consider using a cross-platform toolkit library like e.g. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/): it gives you an abstraction (the Qt API) which should work on several operating systems.

Comment: Minor nit: use std::ostringstream (note the "o" after "::") instead of std::stringstream.

Comment: I disagree with the general sentiment here. If you're writing a Windows application, you have an absolutely unavoidable dependency upon the Win32 API. Therefore, there's no real reason for hand-wringing about portable code: it's not going to be portable anyway. I'm all for writing portable code in the abstract, but you have to be careful to apply decision rules like this in context. If you're already including the Windows headers, and there's a function there that does exactly what you want, you might as well use it.

Comment: Once could argue that if the person is asking, he does not know that well... And he should encapsulate the non portable part of his code...

Comment: Upvoted despite sharing Cody Gray's sentiment. I have no qualms using Windows-specific functions in such circumstances, when they happen to be clearly better. But neither `StringCchPrintf` nor `_sprintf_s` is.

Comment: BTW, I never used Windows (my last Microsoft system was MSDOS6), so I have no idea of why the `_sprintf_s` exist there... :-)